# Why is this future returning [[], []] instead of [[<users>], [<posts>]]

Tags: json, flutter, for-loop, supabase, supabase-database

I am trying to make one source of data for all of the screens of my app to share so that if one is reloaded, the data is also reloaded on the others. The goal: fetch lists of user/post documents (Json data), turn each item in those lists into either a `UserSearchResult` or `Post` object, return a list containing a list of `UserSearchResult` and a list of `Post` (example: `[[user, user, user], [post, post, post]]`), then use that in a `FutureBuilder`. I had working code but I switcherom Firebase to self-hosting Supabase and they return data differently which meant I had to change the function. So far, the only thing working is getting the data as `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`. After that, the `for in` loops are not working. This is complicated to explain but I have commented the code below to make it more clear.

```
  Future<List> fetchUsersAndPosts() async {

    List<Map<String, dynamic>> userDocs =
        await Supabase.db.from('profiles').select();
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> postsDocs =
        await Supabase.db.from('posts').select();

    /// Prints correctly
    print('Supa: $userDocs');
    print('Supa: $postsDocs');

    List<UserSearchResult> usersList = [];
    List<Post> postsList = [];

    /// Does not complete
    for (var userDoc in userDocs) {
      /// Printed but nothing after that works
      print('New user json: $userDoc');

      final profileInfo = ProfileInfoObject.fromJson(userDoc);

      Profile profile = Profile(profileInfo, []);

      UserSearchResult user = (UserSearchResult(profile, userDoc['uid']));
      print('New post: $user');

      usersList.add(user);
      print('users with new: $usersList');
    }

    /// Does not complete
    for (var postDoc in postsDocs) {
      print('New post json: $postDoc');

      final post = Post.fromJson(postDoc);
      print('New post: $post');
      postsList.add(post);
      print('Posts with new: $postsList');

      usersList.where((u) => u.uid == post.uid).single.profile.posts.add(post);
      print('Users with posts: $usersList');
    }

    /// Prints empty
    print('usersList: $usersList');
    print('postsList: $postsList');

    postsList.sort((a, b) {
      return a.date.compareTo(b.date);
    });

    /// Returns empty lists [[], []]
    return Future.value([usersList, postsList]);
  }
```

In theory this should be easier than Firebase because with this I get the Json data immediately instead of dealing with the weird Firebase objects. I think it has something to do witht the `for in` loops being skipped before returning but I don't know how to fix this.

What's printed:

1. The list of maps
2. "New user josn: *user*" **ONCE**
3. Nothing after that is printed.

**Goal:**

1. Recieve data
2. Create list of maps `userDocs` and `postsDocs`
3. For each item in that list create a `UserSearchResult` or `Post` and add it to the `usersList` or `postsList`
4. Once **all** users/posts have been added, `return [usersList, postsList]`

Comment: At first glance I don't see the error. But what do you mean exactly with "Does not complete". Just debug your code line by line. Putting prints after every line if necessary and then it shouldn't be that hard to figure out what exactly is happening

Comment: It seems to be stopping right after `print('New user json: $userDoc');`. I added a bunch of prints for everything and updated the code sample but nothing prints after that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.

```
  Future<UserSearchResult> getUserObject(Map<String, dynamic> userDoc) {
    ProfileInfoObject profileInfo = ProfileInfoObject.fromJson(userDoc);
    print('New profile: $profileInfo');

    Profile profile = Profile(profileInfo, []);

    UserSearchResult user =
        (UserSearchResult(profile, userDoc['uid'].toString()));
    print('New user: ${user.toString()}');

    return Future.value(user);
  }

  Future<Post> getPostObject(Map<String, dynamic> postDoc) {
    Post post = Post.fromJson(postDoc);
    print('New post: ${post.toString()}');

    return Future.value(post);
  }

  Future<List> fetchUsersAndPosts() async {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> userDocs =
        await Supabase.db.from('profiles').select();
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> postsDocs =
        await Supabase.db.from('posts').select();

    print('Supa: $userDocs');
    print('Supa: $postsDocs');

    List<UserSearchResult> usersList = [];
    List<Post> postsList = [];

    userDocs.forEach((userDoc) async {
      UserSearchResult user = await getUserObject(userDoc);

      usersList.add(user);
      print('users with new: $usersList');
    });

    postsDocs.forEach((postDoc) async {
      print('New post json: $postDoc');

      Post post = await getPostObject(postDoc);
      postsList.add(post);
      print('Posts with new: $postsList');

      postsList.sort((a, b) {
        return b.date.compareTo(a.date);
      });

      usersList.where((u) => u.uid == post.uid).single.profile.posts.add(post);
      print('Users with posts: $usersList');
    });

    usersList.forEach((user) {
      user.profile.posts.sort((a, b) {
        return b.date.compareTo(a.date);
      });
    });

    print('usersList: $usersList');
    print('postsList: $postsList');

    return Future.value([usersList, postsList]);
  }
```